# Question regarding a factorial design and the main effect of one of its factor

Tags: estimation, experiment-design, blocking, fractional-factorial

Suppose we consider the following $2^4$ factorial design with factors A, B, C and D in the usual order.

$Block1 - (0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(1,0,1,0),(1,1,1,1),(1,1,0,1),(0,0,1,0).$

$Block2 - (0,0,1,1),(0,1,1,0),(1,0,0,1),(1,1,0,0),(1,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1).$

$Block3 - (0,1,0,0),(0,1,1,1),(1,0,0,0),(1,0,1,1).$

Can anyone provide me with a hint as to how do I examine that the main effect of A is estimable ?